# Enterprise library logging extended properties

Tags: .net, logging

I'm using an enterprise logging library to log the issue in .net MVC application. I would like to log 2 extra properties (Origin, StackTrace) along with the predefined properties.

For that I'm using LogEntry.ExtenedProperties().

```
LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry
{
  TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
  Message = message,
  EventId = (int)eventId,
  Severity = severity
};

LogEntry.ExtendedProperties.Add("Origin",origin.ToString());

If (exception!=null)
{
 LogEntry.ExtendedProperties.Add ("StackTrace", exception.StackTrace);
}
```

In web config,

```
<formaters>
     <add type=Microsoft.Practices. EnterpriseLibrary.Loging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Loging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=nutral, template= "[{timestamp(local)}] [{severity}] [{eventid}] {message} {newline}{dictionary({key} : {value}{newline} }" name = "Default Text Formatter" />
</formatter>
```

This gives the following output:

```
[16/04/2022 5:10:25 PM] [Error] [3] Error : Object Reference not set to an instance of an object
Origin : VerificationService
StackTrace : at VerificationService (string ProtocalVersion, Boolean is ObjectMapped) at System.Collections.Generic.List.Foreach(Action action)
```

My requirement is the error log should be as follows (stackTrace should be in the second line, all other property logging information  in the first line)

```
[16/04/2022 5:10:25 PM] [Error] [3] [VerificationService] Error : Object Reference not set to an instance of an object
StackTrace : at VerificationService (string ProtocalVersion, Boolean is ObjectMapped) at System.Collections.Generic.List.Foreach(Action action)
```

Since the Origin and stackTrace properties were added with the help of ExtendedProperties, I don't know how to split those properties. I tried some combinations but no luck.